# The imaginary part $~v~$ is equal to $~\frac{1}{2} \log(x+y)~$ . Verify whether it is harmonic or not?

Tags: harmonic-functions

The imaginary part $~v~$ is equal to $~\frac{1}{2} \log(x+y)~$ . Verify whether it is harmonic or not?

Relayed to complex functions ie harmonic functions

Comment: Welcome! Sorry but your question doesn't have any context and doesn't show any working from your part. Try and edit your question and provide something to start with so as someone can answer. It can get downvoted if you don't. Also use mathjax for writing equations

Answer (score 0):

$$v=\frac{1}{2} \log(x+y)$$
Since $v(x,y)$ is a polynomial function, so all partial verivatives $v_x,~v_y,~v_{xx},~v_{yy},~v_{xy}$ are defined and continuous where $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$.

Now $$v_x=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{x+y},~~~~~~v_y=\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{x+y}$$
$$v_{xx}=-~\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+y)^2},~~~~~~v_{yy}=-~\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}$$

Here $$v_{xx}+v_{yy}=-\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\ne 0\qquad \text{when}\quad (x,y)\ne (0,0)$$

Hence $~v~$ is not harmonic when $~(x,y)\ne (0,0)~$.

---

> **Harmonic function:**
>
> If   $~\phi_x(x,y),~\phi_y(x,y),~\phi_{xx}(x,y),~\phi_{yy}(x,y),~\phi_{xy}(x,y)~$  are all continuous, and if  $~\phi(x,y)~$  satisfies Laplace's equation$$\phi_{xx}+\phi_{yy}= 0~,$$ then  $~\phi(x,y)~$  is called a harmonic function.